# Haskell: Trouble with let statement

Tags: parsing, haskell, syntax

I'm trying to write a function in Haskell and I'm trying to start the function with two lets followed by the answer.

```
split :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
split x y z = 
    let first = ( x (y))
    let last = ( y (Z))
    (first, last)
```

I'm getting a "parse error on input 'let'" starting on the 2nd let statement. Why is this, and how can I fix this?

Comment: May I suggest: `split f g x = (fx, gx) where {fx = f x; gx = g x}`? Of course you might also omit the local bindings entirely and inline them, `split f g x = (f x, g x)`. — BTW this combinator is more commonly called _fanout_, not “split”, and the standard version of it is [`&&&`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) (it's more general, but your signature is the most common special case of it).

Comment: Haskell does not have a `let` statement (or indeed *any* statements). The assignment-like `let` clause is a part of the `do` syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
split :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
```

This says your first argument is a function from some type `a` to some type `b` and your second argument is a function from some type `a` to some type `c`.

```
split x y z =
```

So `x :: a -> b` and `y :: a -> c`.

```
    let first = ( x (y))
```

That means you are trying to apply the function `x` to `y` but this won't work because `x` expects an argument of type `a` and `y` is of type `a -> c`. This is wrong.

```
    let last = ( y (Z))
```

There is no `Z`, check your capitalizations.

```
    (first, last)
```

Syntactically, you need an `in`.  The syntax is:

```
let var1 = expr1
    var2 = expr2
in expr3WithVars1And2InScope
```

A small exception: When using `do` blocks you don't use `in` because that is implicitly the remainder of the `do` block.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need here to work with a `let`, you can just make an expression with a simple 2-tuple:

```
split :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
split x y z = (x z, y z)
```

or you can simplify this to:

```
split :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
split x y = (,) <$> x <*> y
```

or even simpler:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

split :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
split = liftA2 (,)
```